# Unable to add multiple line in a JEditorPane

Tags: java, text, jeditorpane

I'm using a `JEditorPane` to display some text. The problem is that I can't add multiple lines.

My code right now

```
public class Window extends JFrame {
private JEditorPane text = new JEditorPane();

public Window() {
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    setTitle("test");
    setSize(500, 350);
    setResizable(false);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    text.setEditable(false);
    text.setContentType("text/html");

    text.setText("<b>Some bold text</b><br>");
    text.setText(text.getText() + "<br>Some text that is not bold but here <b>it is</b>");

    getContentPane().add(text, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    setVisible(true);
}
```

}

When it is in the same line ther is no problem, `<br>` create a new line. But if it is in multiple statements, I can't get it to work.

It need to be in multiple statements because every statement is going to be a `if` condition later on.

How can i make it do multiple lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the JEditorPane wraps the text in  `<html><body> ... </body></html>` elements. For instance, when executing the following:

```
text.setText("<b>Some bold text</b><br>");
System.out.println("text content:\n" + text.getText());
```

You get this output:

```
text content:
<html>
  <head>

  </head>
  <body>
    <b>Some bold text</b><br>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thus you need to either store the previous text before it is wrapped, or insert the addtional content before the `</body>`

For instance, in a very simple implementation, you could add the following attribute and method to your class:

```
private StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

public String appendText(String text) {
  return sb.append(text).toString();
}
```

Then, you could change your previous statements to set the text into:

```
...
text.setText(appendText("<b>Some bold text</b><br>"));
text.setText(appendText("<br>Some text that is not bold but here <b>it is</b>"));
...
```

which results in the desired behavior:

[image]

Comment: so when i do `text.setText(text.getText + <b>bla bla</b>);` doesn't it reset the text in the `JEditorPane`?

Comment: No it won't. Instead it will replace the text with `<html><body>previous text</body></html><b>bla bla</b>`. Anything after the `</body></html>`will thus be ignored.

Comment: Any suggestion on how i should proceed?

Comment: So if i get this right append put the text after whats already written. It "kinda" do a `getText()` by itself and then add the new text afterward. Thanks for the answer, it's really appreciated.